# If item is selected show specific item | Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need a specific div to only show when a specific item is selected.

Here is my progress so far: [Progress](http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/457/)

You will see in HTML comments that div5 needs to show if option 2 is selected however, on default div5 will be set to display none.

All suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't you just add a conditional to check if `data-target='2'` is selected, then reveal `#div5`, otherwise hide it?

Like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3e66n/).

Code used:

```
if ($(this).data('target') == "2") {
    $("#div5").show();
} else {
    $("#div5").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) you can specify a boolean to showOrHide, so you could modify the code with the following to simplify the showing and hiding and cater for the special condition.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SUj73/)

#### JavaScript

```
var $options = $('.showSingle');
var $targets = $('.targetDiv');

$('.showSingle').on('click', function () {
    $options.removeClass('selected');
    $targets.hide();

    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('#div' + $(this).data('target')).show();

    $('#div5').toggle($(this).data('target') === 2);
});

$('.showSingle').first().click();
```

#### CSS

```
.targetDiv, #div5 {
    dislpay: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

All you need is :

```
$("#div5").toggle($(this).data('target')==2);
```

and it looks like this:

```
$('.showSingle').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $('.targetDiv').hide();
    $('#div' + $(this).data('target')).show();
    $("#div5").toggle($(this).data('target')==2);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/468/)

Answer (score 2):

you can do it by using on click action to show div5

this is jsfiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/461/)

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/SRQTv/1/

```
var target = $(this).data('target')
                    .toString()
                    .split(',')
                    .map(function(i) { return '#div' + i; })
                    .join(', ');

$(target).show();
```

With this modification we're able to specify dependent comma separated divs like `1,2,3`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a class to hide / show items. Say you have the class `.displayNone`, and all divs start with that class, then you only need to remove it for the selected div.